# Android локализация для всех регионов

Tags: android, локализация, locale

Создал папку values-ru, но когда захожу с украинского языка или белорусского, то получаю ошибку.

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d0037
```

Работает, только когда создам для каждого языка папку. Подпапки типа value-ru-rUK так же не работают. В чём может быть ошибка и как её избежать?

Comment: А просто `values` есть папка? Из неё берутся ресурсы, если нет отдельных ресурсов для нужной локали.

Comment: Есть такая, если в неё добавляю ресурсы, то из неё берёт. Но я хочу, чтобы для всех русских регионов работало именно с папки values-ru

Comment: Поместите тогда русские ресурсы в папку `values`, а для остальных переводов делайте отдельные папки. Можно ещё создать [AliasResources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources), но для строк всё равно придётся копировать файлы в папки для каждой локали. В общем почитайте по ссылке, там много всего про локализацию ресурсов.

Comment: Все ID ресурсов перечисляемые в папках values-xxx должны обязательно присутствовать в стандартной values

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка указывает, что система не нашла String, ресурс по данному ID.

1.Проверьте, что у вас есть изначальная папка value.

2.Убедитесь, что переменные, которые вы добавляете в другие языки, также присутствуют в папке value.

3.Сделать Clean Project.